# Problemas al realizar el setItem token en el local storage con React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

Estoy teniendo problemas para realizar el localStorage.setItem('token')con mi aplicación de React.js, para realizar el login de un usuario.
Os comento que la api la tengo con Django rest framework y me he dado cuenta de que me manda dos tokens, un refresh y otro access. Por lo que entiendo que debo utilizar el access  para logearme. EL problema es que no consigo enviar el token al local storage.

Utilizo Flux para la gestion de las actions.

el código que enseño es la versión más simple que se me ha ocurrido, para que se viera lo que quiero hacer.

````
            login: (email, password,) => {
                fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login', {
                    method: "POST",
                    mode: "cors",
                    headers: {
                        
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password})
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => console.log(data))
                    .then(data => localStorage.setItem("token", data.token))
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
                    
            }, ```

[![Print de pntalla donde se vé que recibo el token][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C51AH.jpg
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo hay que crear una constante donde se recoge el token, en concreto en este caso de la data.

```
    .then(data => {
        const {access} = data;
        if (access === undefined || access == null) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.replace("/");
            }, 4000);
            toast.warn("Ha ocurrido un error. Inténtalo de nuevo", {
                position: "top-right",
                autoClose: 4000,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined
            
            });
        } else {
                setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.replace("/Offers");
            }, 1500);
            toast.warn("Ya estás logeado!", {
                position: "top-right",
                autoClose: 1500,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined
            
            });
            
        }
        localStorage.setItem('jwt-token', access)
    })
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    
},
```

Comment: En lugar de escribir "resuelto", [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.